# Python - How to find an item in a list

Tags: python, list

...and compare it with another list to get the same item in the same index/position.

Eg.

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

b = [a, b, c, d, e]

I want the highest number in list *a* so:

> 5

And then, I compare it with list *b* to get the item, which is on the same position as the highest number in list *a*:

> e

I apologize for the poorly worded question but this is the best I can explain it.

Comment: if you just want the last item call `b[len(a) - 1]` instead as that is much faster

Answer (score 1):

One-liner: `b[a.index(max(a))]`

However, this makes two pass through the list, i.e. first with `max(a)`, and second with `a.index`.

The snippet below makes only one pass:

```
max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(a), key=lambda p: p[1])
print(b[max_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

python has this great built in array function called `index` that will take care of what you need.

in your example: `x = b[a.index(5)]` which takes `a` and gets the index of `5` (which is 4) and then assigns the item in `b` at that index to the variable `x` so that you can do whatever evaluations you may need.